# Implementing depth-first search using a stack

Tags: rust

I've come across a problem that requires doing DFS on a tree defined like such:

```
pub struct TreeNode {
   pub val: i32,
   pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
   pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}
```

I want to use the non-recursive version of the algorithm with an explicit stack. The tree is read-only and the values in the tree are not guaranteed to be unique (they can't be used to identify a node).

Problem is, that the iterative version requires a `visited` data structure. Normally, in C++, I'd just use an `std::set` with node pointers for implementing `visited`. How would I do the same (or analogous) in Rust? There doesn't seem to be an easy way to get a pointer to an object that I can use in a set.

Comment: Is it a tree or a graph? If a tree I don't see why you need a `visited` structure. If a graph, using `Rc<_>` will create reference cycles so your structure will leak memory.

Comment: Surely if it's a tree, there can't be cycles in it. Why a `visited` data structure?

Comment: Off topic, but whenever I see `Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>`, I’m reminded that Rust tries really hard to do what others do trivially and it sucks.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar When you say "others", are you talking about garbage collected languages, or languages with weakly typed pointers? In the former case, I'd say that the implementation is all but trivial. It certainly pushes the ownership semantics to the responsibility of the user, but I wouldn't say that it sucks. In the latter case, it makes it trivial to write erroneous code with invalid memory access, which arguably sucks more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, we don't need to keep track of visited if we know there are no circular dependencies. Normally binary trees don't have circular dependencies so we may be able to assume it simply is not an issue. In this case, we can use a `VecDeque` as our 'stack' queue.

```rust
type TreeNodeRef = Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>;

pub struct TreeNode {
   pub val: i32,
   pub left: Option<TreeNodeRef>,
   pub right: Option<TreeNodeRef>,
}

 pub fn dfs(root: TreeNodeRef, target: i32) -> Option<TreeNodeRef> {
    let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
    queue.push_back(root);
    
    while let Some(node) = queue.pop_front() {
        // Check if this is the node we are looking for
        if node.borrow().val == target {
            return Some(node)
        }
        
        // Add left and write to the back of the queue for DFS
        let items = node.borrow();
        if let Some(left) = &items.left {
            queue.push_front(left.clone());
        }
        
        if let Some(right) = &items.right {
            queue.push_front(right.clone());
        }
    }
    
    // Search completed and node was not found
    None
}
```

However, if we need to keep a list of visited nodes, we can cheat a little. An `Rc<T>` is just a boxed value with a reference count so we can extract a pointer from it. Even though we can not compare TreeNodes, we can store where they are kept in memory. When we do that, the solution looks like this:

```rust
pub fn dfs(root: TreeNodeRef, target: i32) -> Option<TreeNodeRef> {
    let mut visited = HashSet::new();
    let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
    queue.push_back(root);
    
    while let Some(node) = queue.pop_front() {
        // Check node has not been visited yet
        if visited.contains(&Rc::as_ptr(&node)) {
            continue
        }
        
        // Insert node to visited list
        visited.insert(Rc::as_ptr(&node));
        
        if node.borrow().val == target {
            return Some(node)
        }
        
        let items = node.borrow();
        
        if let Some(left) = &items.left {
            queue.push_front(left.clone());
        }
        
        if let Some(right) = &items.right {
            queue.push_front(right.clone());
        }
    }
    
    None
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6359f132cb60667b0a424e426ceda932)

You may also find it interesting to look at the bottom 2 code examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71190546/5987669) to see how a generic search method could be made.

**Edit:** Alternatively, here is a [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f68f970f5986255c46074f3ca0dac11c) of how this could be done with a regular `Vec` and `Rc::clone(x)` as recommended by @isaactfa.

Comment: I think you're doing breadth-first search here. Depth-first only needs a stack, not a queue. Also, I think it's preferred to call `Rc::clone(left)` instead of `left.clone()` so it doesn't coerce into the wrong impl.

Comment: @isaactfa You're right I had it doing BFS by accident. However, I changed the variable to `queue` since that it how all of the textbooks I have seen on this subject describe it. Nodes get popped from the queue, checked for a match, then expanded and placed back into the queue in accordance with the search policy. As for the clone, I get that `Rc::clone(x)` is generally better, but I generally prefer the look of `x.clone()`. To play devils advocate, if `TreeNodeRef` is changed to a different type, `Rc::clone` will no longer be correct. Coercion is not an issue since we add `root` at the start.

Comment: That's true about `Rc::clone`, I just like to keep it consistent so I don't mess it up when it does matter :) I would disagree on the queue though. Traditionally a queue is a FIFO data structure, which is what we want for BFS, whereas a stack is a LIFO data structure, which we want for DFS. But while the name isn't that important, I reckon using `Vec` instead of `VecDeque` _is_ probably better because it's a simpler and more performant data structure.